# Gulp won't move images into dist folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I haven't been able to find any sufficient elaborated answers to my question so thought I'd ask.

Here is my code:

My watch tasks:

```
function watchEverything() {
  watch('./src/html/**/*.html', {
    ignoreInitial: false
  },
    moveHTML);
  watch('./src/sass/**/*.scss', {
    ignoreInitial: false
  },
    processSass);
  watch('./src/js/**/*.js', {
    ignoreInitial: false
  },
    babelAllTheWay)
  watch('.src/img/**/*.{gif,jpg,png,svg}', {
    ignoreInitial: false
  },
    processImages);
}
```

and here is the gulp task itself:

```
function processImages() {
 return src('.src/img/**/*.{gif,jpg,png,svg}')
   .pipe(dest('dist/assets/img'))
   .pipe(reload())
}
```

What is the problem here?

The path?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll kick yourself ;>}  `.src/etc` should be `./src/etc.` note the backslash - in both your `watch` and function.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaa - Thank you Mark | Kicked myself in the nuts for that one